# persist data in a class for reuse by another function

Tags: ios, swift

Here is a swift class file:

```
import Foundation


class DataPreparation {


// Variables
var userCountries = [String]() //Just 1 or 2 countries
var correspondingFullArrays = [[String]]()


//Get and set raw user countries from current image
func getUserCountries(countries: [String]) ->  [String] {
    userCountries = countries
    return userCountries
}

func getCorrespondingFullArraysToUserCountries() {

    println(userCountries) //Is empty

}
```

On a separate file viewController, the 2 methods lisOfCountries and getCorrespondingFullArraysToUserCountries are invoked independently one after the other:

```
 DataPreparation().getUserCountries(otherArray[0])
 DataPreparation().getCorrespondingFullArraysToUserCountries()
```

Problem is that second method can't access userCountries data set by first method because it is empty.
My guess, and you will correct me if i'm wrong, is that variables get destroyed after each method call.
So how are we supposed to handle small data persistance from one function to another, when they are called separatly ? I could of course regroup all in a single function, but is this the good way of doing ?

Comment: You have a variable called lisOfCountries, but I don't see a method, called lisOfCountries, in your post. Class variables (properties) shouldn't be be destroyed after each method call.

Comment: Indeed, listOfCountries is defined in another file

Comment: I think you need to add some more information to your post to make it clear what you have in each file, and in what order things are happening.

Comment: ok, I added some more information, as well as remove the listOfCountries that only confuses purpose here as it is not used in this simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each line of this code:

```
DataPreparation().getUserCountries(otherArray[0])
DataPreparation().getCorrespondingFullArraysToUserCountries()
```

you are creating a new instance of `DatePreparation`, and then calling a method on it. Since you do not assign the instance to a variable, the instance is destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope, which in this case corresponds to the same line where it is instantiated.

You should create an instance (and not 2), and assign to a variable. Then, you can call methods on that instance:

```
var dataPreparation = DataPreparation()
dataPreparation.getUserCountries(otherArray[0])
dataPreparation.getCorrespondingFullArraysToUserCountries()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I suspected the variables got destroyed... just didn't knew why. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling the function `getCorrespondingFullArraysToUserCountries` on `DataPreparation()` you are creating another instance each time.You are creating `DataPreparation()` instance each time. instead use

```
//create instance only first time
var dataPreparation:DataPreparation = DataPreparation()

//call methods on same instance
dataPreparation.getUserCountries(otherArray[0])
dataPreparation.getCorrespondingFullArraysToUserCountries()
```